# Difference between the time complexity required to build Binary search tree and AVL tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, time-complexity, avl-tree

While I was learning Binary search tree(Balanced and unbalanced), I come up with questions which I need to resolve:

1. If I construct a Binary search tree(Not necessary to be balanced) , using n elements then what is the total time complexity for tree construction ?
2. If an AVL tree is constructed from n elements then what is the time complexity to contruct that AVL tree ?

Should it be more than nlog(n) ?  because we need lots of rotation for AVL tree construction .

I know that insertion and deletion operation in AVL tree will be of log(n) order(same is true if binary search tree constructed with random elements has log(n) height).

But I need to know about overall  tree construction cost and how it varies as I need to use balanced search tree for sorting purpose .

Comment: 1. average case: O(nlgn) ; worst case: O(n*n) 2. O(nlgn)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. It can be proven that the expected height of a BST satisifies E[Xn] <= 3 log n + O(1), so the expected time is O(n log n). The worst case is still O(n^2), e.g. if the input is sorted.
2. O(n log n) because the amount of rotations for every added element is O(1).

Comment: 1. needs some detailed arguments: why does the average-case result apply to every intermediate tree?

Answer (score 36):

Let us start with constructing an [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree). To create a tree you have to insert `n` elements in it. To insert the element in a balanced tree you need `log(n)`. Therefore you end up with `O(n*log(n))`.

Coming back to a regular [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree). It is counter-intuitive, but it depends how do you construct this tree. If you do not know all the elements of BST in advance ([online algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm)) then you have to insert each of `n` elements one after another. If you are extremely unlucky, the complexity of insert is `O(n)` and thus it deteriorates to `O(n^2)`.

Notice that this situation is highly unlikely, but still possible.

**But you can still achieve `O(nlog(n))` if you know all the elements in advance.** You can sort them `O(nlog(n))` and then insert the elements in the following order. [Take the middle element and insert it as a root](http://leetcode.com/2010/11/convert-sorted-array-into-balanced.html), then recursively do the same for both parts that are left. You will end up creating balanced BST, inserting `n` elements using `log(n)`.